# How to remove some letters form a variable in bash

Tags: bash, github

I have this Url

```
Https://github.com/RayaneQH/test.git
```

I want to write a bash script that take this input and output only the test (the repository)
Note:
If there is any way to do this using git , i prefer that you give the two solutions , one in bash and one in git

I google it and i didn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

You can use [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) of your shell to remove the largest prefix pattern:

```
url='https://github.com/RayaneQH/test.git'
url="${url##*/}"
```

This will remove everything up to and including the final slash.

I don't know how this could be done with Git, since Git is a version control system and not a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

"with git"

Using the [github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-repository) with the [github CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli)

```bash
gh api 'repos/RayaneQH/test' --jq '.name'
```

would output (if the repo existed)

```
test
```

Omit the `--jq` option to get all data about the repo in JSON format.